# How can I create a single Slack window that contains all my recent messages?

Tags: slack

Slack does a great job of making a popup appear on my computer when I receive messages that should be looked at.  Unfortunately, those popups are transient and disappear after a few seconds on my Linux box.

Is there a way I can have a slack window, channel, etc, that just contains recently received messages I can scroll through?